# Rebuild collection in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'd like to "rebuild" my collection atomically, which means delete all existing documents and populate it from scratch.
The thing is, since transactions are not supported there is a small time gap that the collection is empty, which is what I want to avoid.

Is there a way to perform such action in an atomically matter? so there will be no point where the collection is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new collection with a different name and then use [rename](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.rename) command to rename the new collection and drop the existing collection (using `dropTarget=True` option).

There are several caveats though:

- The command will invalidate open cursors which interrupts queries that
  are currently returning data.
- `renameCollection` blocks all database activity for the duration of the operation.
- `renameCollection` is not compatible with sharded collections.
- If the `renameCollection` operation does not complete, the target collection and indexes will not be usable and will require manual intervention to clean up.

You can find more info in the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/renameCollection/#dbcmd.renameCollection).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot.